# wc -l command issues in SunOs to Linux migration

Tags: linux, solaris, wc

We are migrating from SunOS to Linux. I'm facing some problem with `wc -l` command. When I used `wc -l <file_name>`, SunOS is giving leading spaces before count where as Linux there are no leading spaces. This is causing failures of row count validation scripts of my jobs. I tried to create a function like this to append some leading spaces in Linux

```
wc () {    /usr/bin/wc "$@" | sed 's/^/       /';  }
```

however its not working for all row count values. How to solve this issue rather changing 200+ scripts of all my jobs.

Comment: Is it "not working" because some scripts call 'wc' themselves and don't care about your function, or because it's running but not prepending spaces to every line (somehow?)

Comment: if your scripts are broken by leading (or trailing) whitespace then fix your scripts - they are too fragile to be trusted.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the behavior I see for Linux (and OSX) matches SunOS reasonably well, with some differences for the number of digits.

HPUX follows the description in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wc.html), which shows no leading blanks in the format:

```
"%d %d %d %s\n", <newlines>, <words>, <bytes>, <file>
```

You can imitate SunOS's format using awk

```sh
#!/bin/sh
wc () {
    /usr/bin/wc "$@" | \
    awk '{
        for (n = 0; n < NF-1; ++n) {
            printf("%8d ", $n);
        }
        printf "%s\n", $NF; }'
}

wc "$@"
```

I intentionally left a blank between columns to avoid the problem noted in the POSIX rationale.

Answer (score 0):

The SunOS `wc` output matches the definitions of SYSVr4.

I cannot see any real divergence to the POSIX standard. Even the build-in `wc` from ksh93 matches the `SunOS` output and a recent Solaris 11 even uses the `wc` library implementation from `ksh93` with no change in the output.

If your scripts have problems with the output from one or another `wc` implementation, this is a strong hint for a non-portable script that should be fixed.